# get block-scoped variable in class instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I know (or I think I know) how scopes in JavaScript work so I suppose it can  be impossible BUT: is there a way to get to the block (function) scoped variables in a class instance?

```
class Test {
  run() {
    const running = true;
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.run();

console.log(?) -> here I would like to get info that `running` variable was created
```

I can't create another function inside Test class. I've just got the instance.

FYI: the problem I try to solve is broader and has to do with 3rd-party library.

Comment: var app = { running: true }; var Test = { run: function() { return app.running; } }; var testInstance = new Test(); var testRunMethod = testInstance.run; testRunMethod(); app.running can be globally accessed switch. the run method can be a property of the test object and therefore can be copied and reused.

Comment: @daddygames you might want to post that as an answer

Comment: Is your goal to access the value of `running` or are you attempting to find out which variables were created inside the function `run`?

Comment: you should design more with this for those variable class Test {
      run() {
         this.running = true;
      }
    } then you can access them easily and its more proper for class usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know how scopes in JavaScript work so I suppose it can be impossible

Yes indeed. That's what *block scope* means: the variable is only available to code in that very block, i.e. between the `{ … }` braces of the `run` method.

> ```
> test.run();
> console.log(?) // here I would like to get info that `running` variable was created
> ```

No, that's not possible. Notice the the `running` variable doesn't even exist any longer after the `.run()` call ended.

The only way to make the `true` value available to the outside is to change the `run` method, e.g. by making it an object property not a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you change the function `run` you can't access the property within. If you're working with 3rd-party code it's hard but a possible solution would be to overwrite the method by extending the class (you need to go very sure that the 3rd party code doesn't change that much):

```
class ConcreteTest extends Test {
    run() { 
        // option A
        this.running = true

        // option B
        return true;

        // or use both A and B
    }
}
```

The run function would be overwritten so it depends if this is an appropriate or working solution.

Doesn't your library provide any API or workaround to solve your issue?

Comment: That`s what I thought. The idea with extending 3rd party is a good one though. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = { running: true }; 
var Test = { run: function() { return app.running; } }; 
var testInstance = new Test(); 
var testRunMethod = testInstance.run; testRunMethod();
```

app.running can be globally accessed switch. the run method can be a property of the test object and therefore can be copied and reused.

Comment: that's not working if the function doesn't return anything

Comment: the function returns the value of app.running

Comment: yes - your code works, but he states that he is using some 3rd party framework which he (I think) can't edit that easily.

Comment: @daddygames thank you for your answer. It's true though that I can't modify the code directly.